# CodePush for FlutterIO

Tags: flutter, code-push

I already know about CodePush for Cordova & ReactNative.

Source : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/codepush/

Is there any CodePush Solution for FlutterIO on Production Environment?

Or is it already supported as it already support ReactNative?

Thank You.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is technically possible for flutter to support code push as dart does have JIT needed for such feature. Technology is not the blocker and they might eventually roll out this feature.

Follow [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14330) for more informations and being updated on code push support for flutter.

Comment: Thank You Adnaan. Seems like the direction is that apps can be updated without user acknowledgement / automatic via Code Push.

Comment: Yeah it is one of the reasons why react-native is hot despite its many problems. But you shouldn't be too happy for it as ios does wonders. They are kind of blocking or in the way to block all hot code push. Read [this](https://www.silicon.co.uk/mobility/apple-hot-code-push-206922) and [this](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=13817557)

Comment: Still no support for this feature :/

Comment: If I understand correctly, JIT is good for debug mode to support hot reload. For release, to guarantee the performance, AOT is used instead.

Answer (score 2):

ReactNative and Flutter are not related, although they both use reactive concepts. ReactNative and Cordova both use javascript in the app side, Flutter uses compiled dart code. So support for ReactNative is not relevant for Flutter.

As you can see [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/flutter-dev/YwzItp1pxJo/7bFGDLvxBAAJ) there are currently no plans to support any form of dynamic updates.

Answer (score 1):

it is not supported at the moment but this issue is being discussed here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14330

Answer (score 1):

**You can use this service that gives you this feature and it works**

[ShoreBird](https://shorebird.dev/)

**this is code push for flutter**

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/referencing](/help/referencing)

Comment: please check the documents https://docs.shorebird.dev/

Comment: what documents? how does that answer my question?

Answer (score 0):

flutter_code_push package

Check [this](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_code_push)